# How to disable the desktop previews in the app menu?

Tags: gnome, 22.04

[image: Desktop previews in the app menu]

How can I disable these? In the Settings, selecting 1 desktop doesn't help, and it still shows up there.

I don't use multiple desktops, and the Activities menu already exists to switch between desktops, so this ability doesn't need to be duplicated.

How can I remove these from the app menu?